# What is this.props (Meteor with React Tutorial)

Tags: meteor, reactjs, properties, ecmascript-6

I'm just starting to learn Meteor with React using es6, and I'm having trouble understanding this.props.  Where does it come from?  I don't have any code where I define it for the class myself.  Thank you in advance.

This is a portion of my code in simple-todos/imports/ui/App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';

import Task from './Task.jsx';

class App extends Component { 
  renderTasks() {
    return this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
      <Task key={task._id} task={task} />
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the React documentation? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#using-props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This props contains the properties that are passed to the component upon creation. E.g:

```
<SomeComponent someProperty={'foo'} />
```

Now inside `SomeComponent` you can now access `someProperty` as `this.props.someProperty`

Read more about using props [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#using-props).

Comment: Thank you, is this correct? 

The `<someComponent someProperty={'foo'} />` tag calls the constructor for someComponent, which creates a jSON object (a table of key value pairs).  The jSON object is then converted into `props`, a member of the current component. 

So `this.props` contains all of the properties that you passed to the tag (eg. `someProperty={'foo'}`) plus any default properties.  Whenever you want to access a property of that component (`SomeComponent`) you have to access it through `this.props.someProperty`.

Comment: Sound about right, but I'll leave the linked documentation to answer the technicalities.

Comment: But the `tasks` is not passed in any object in component in the `simple-todos` tutorial, so why does it know `this.props.tasks`

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to make more "arbitrary" components. For example, say you have a list that fetches from a server.

```
export default class List extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  }
  render() {
    return (
      //you can now be sure that the proptypes are what you wanted them to be.
    )
  }
}
```

That way, you can just pass the array of `data` to this component

```
<List data={users} />
```